# Silicone material

Tags: materials

How to create silicone material in Blender 3.X, such as on this image? (Shape doesn't matter - can be a cube).

[image]

Comment: Did you already try to use a little bit of SSS in the principle material node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Carlo says, try a bit of *Subsurface*, also mix with a bit of *Translucent*, lower down the *Specular* and the *Roughness*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I just saw [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/properties/transparency.html#transparency-ior-common) that silicone has IOR value of 4.24 ... Is this what is called "Subsurface IOR" in your image?

Comment: I also saw [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/hardware-and-creative/9781782161301/4/ch04lvl1sec33/creating-a-rubber-material) which looks good, but it is an old version of Blender. And the instructions are not fully visible...

Comment: Yes maybe tweak the IOR to see if it has any effect